# Load jboss-ejb3.xml file instead ejb-jar.xml in wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am added some custom configuration in jboss-ejb3.xml file for wildfly. So instead of loading configuration from ejb-jar.xml, it should load from jboss-ejb3.xml file.
But some how it loads ejb-jar.xml file.

is it any configuration required in standalon.xnl file to load this?

Ref-
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+WildFly
The JBoss EJB deployment descriptor, this can be used to override settings from ejb-jar.xml, and to set WildFly specific settings

Comment: Where did you place jboss-ejb3.xml ? Also - do you understand that JBoss will still read ejb-jar.xml but if you have the same settings in jboss-ejb3 that should override them?

Comment: @Disco3 I put in ear/meta-inf folder. ref- https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment+Descriptors+used+In+WildFly "The JBoss EJB deployment descriptor, this can be used to override settings from ejb-jar.xml, and to set WildFly specific settings"