# jboss-ejb3.xml getting schema from

Tags: intellij-idea, xsd, wildfly, descriptor

I am getting a simlar issue as below:
[Load jboss-ejb3.xml file instead ejb-jar.xml in wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514713/load-jboss-ejb3-xml-file-instead-ejb-jar-xml-in-wildfly)

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3189

[schema location error jboss-ejb3.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32031205/schema-location-error-jboss-ejb3-xml)

My issue is that my xsd definition on top of my jboss-ejb3.xml is like this:

```
<jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:s="urn:security:1.1"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
           version="3.1"
           impl-version="2.0">
```

when clicking on http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd it opens jboss_5_0.xsd inside a maven jar: Maven: org.jboss.metadata:jboss-metadata:1.0.0.CR162 in my intelliJ. Seems like this is an old one as it does not have this XSD. now i was under the impression that if it did not find the XSD it will download it, which is why the http link is there in my opinion. but it is not. for ejb-jar_3_1.xsd, however it is getting from intellyJ embedded javaee api lib.

how can I add the right XSD from the net in this case. is it an intelliJ issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've ever been able to determine, you must manually add a reference to a local resource for each XSD that is unknown to Intellij Idea.

This can be configured under `Preferences/Languages & Frameworks/Schemas and DTDs`.

You will not need to download anything from the internet if you have a local copy of WildFly, as it provides copies of all schema in `$WILDFLY_HOME/docs/schema/`.

Comment: Thanks.. will try that.